# Pull Content Regardless of whether user has posts or not

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement

This post relates to WordPress and CIMY User Extra Fields.  I do not think you need a knowledge of the latter to help with this problem, as it seems to be a WordPress issue more than anything.

CIMY User Extra Fields is a plugin that allows registered users to have much more information in their profiles.  You can add as many fields as you want.   You then have to edit "author.php" to pull in the new information.

I am currently using the following code to pull in the new user profile fields:

```
<?php if (have_posts()) { $flag = true;  while (have_posts()) { the_post();
if ($flag) { $value = get_cimyFieldValue(get_the_author_ID(), 'dj-name');
if ($value != NULL) echo "<p><strong>Staff Bio: </strong>" . cimy_uef_sanitize_content($value);
echo "</p>";
$flag = false;    }}}?>
```

The issue is this.  Some of my users have 0 posts and this code will only pull the extra field content for the user if that have 1 post or more.   This is due to the "if (have_posts())" function I suspect.  Is there someway to modify the code to display the information even if the user has 0 posts?

Thanks
Zach

Comment: Is the user's post needed for CIMY to have additional values assigned to them? If not (which would make sense), just remove it from the condition.

Comment: I think its using the users "post" as a way of determining the correct user id and thus the correct extra fields values to retrieve.  If I remove this from the condition, it displays nothing because, I think, it dosen't know which user ID to retrieve the fields for.

Comment: Makes sense. You're editing the author page?

Comment: I edited my answer to retrieve the authorID on the author page.

Comment: Yes, this is all inside author.php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's not a need that a user must have a post to have CIMY values stored (which I assume), you just don't need to check for post-count > 0. You probably have copied that chunk of code over from a post template.

The following example just takes the value, and if it is set, will do the output via echo:

```
<?php
  $authorID = get_the_author_meta('ID');
  $value = get_cimyFieldValue($authorID, 'dj-name');
  if (!empty($value))
    echo '<p><strong>Staff Bio: </strong>'
         , cimy_uef_sanitize_content($value)
         , '</p>'
    ;
?>
```

Comment: @Zach Nicodemous: Must have been an if instead, was some mock-up only. Fixed in the answer.

Comment: Its very strange, but this does not retrieve the value.  It SHOULD, but it just dosent.  It displays the "Staff Bio" text, but not the cimy value.

Comment: Maybe the `$authorID` still is wrong. I picked it from the default themes author template code. Additionally check if the cimy field is the correct field.